# Check Curent Version of Scala inside Dos Command Prompt

Tags: java, scala

Is there any way to find current version of `Scala` that I installed from command prompt?

As you know in command prompt `Java -version` gives us current version of `Java` in the system, and I am wondering if there is any command for `Scala` that gives me its current version.

I follow this instruction to set up `Scala` in **Windows**

> 1. Download the sbt installer from here: http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/sbt.msi
> 2. Run the installer

Verify that sbt is installed correctly: open the Command Prompt and type `sbt sbt-versio`n, you should see the version number of sbt (the first time you run it, sbt will download libraries from the internet). If you have problems installing sbt, ask for help on the forums.

And the tutorial says, it download dependencies when `sbt sbt-versio` is ran or may be I got that wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `scala -version`?

Comment: @GregHewgill yes and it does not work

Comment: @KickButtowski you should say **how** it doesn't work. What output/error do you get?

Comment: 'scala' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. and I am sure I installed it in my pc

Comment: It hasn't been the **DOS** command prompt for ages now...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you just need to go to the Windows shell, start SBT and check the Scala version there, e.g.

```
C:\> sbt

> scala-version

2.9.2 (or whatever)
```

Now, you have the SBT prompt and can type "console" to open the Scala REPL:

```
> console

scala> println("Hello")

Hello
```

You can quit the repl with :q and go back to the SBT prompt

```
scala> :q

>
```

Now you can quit SBT using Ctrl+C to go back to the Windows prompt:

```
C:\>
```

Comment: @markinfo can you formatted your post ? cuz I do not get it at all

Comment: @markinfo when I run println("Hello"), it complians about ( ) ?

Comment: @markinfo can you mention in post that it is impossible to find the  version from DOS?

Comment: it should be scalaVersion not scala-version

Answer (score 27):

This one works for me:

```
sbt scalaVersion
```

Comment: Note: It's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can just run from any command line :

`C:\>scala`

Comment: Is this answer using a newer version than the 5.5 year old question?  Is `sbt` still used?

Comment: i have just tested the command with Scala 2.13, but this command is basically starting "scala shell" while showing scala version. But for sbt idk i never tested it.

Answer (score -2):

You are likely using Scala from within SBT, but you don't have it installed in "stand-alone" mode - or, you simply don't have Scala on your shell path. See if you have SBT on your path (on a Unix-like OS like OS X, Linux, etc.):

```
which sbt
```

If you have SBT on your path, try

```
sbt scala-version
```

Note however that SBT can provide different versions of Scala (the library, compiler, etc.) depending on how your SBT project was set up. This is not a globally applicable version.

If you're on a Unix-like OS (OS X, Linux, etc.) and you suspect you have Scala already installed, you can try searching for where Scala is installed if it's not already on your path

```
sudo find / -name *scala* 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: *What* specifically does not work? Also, what's your OS?

Comment: Also, if you're on a Unix-like OS and you have indexing turned on, you can try "locate" instead of "find":

Comment: Also, if you're on a Unix-like OS and you have indexing turned on, you can try "locate" instead of "find" (locate scala in the terminal).

Comment: I am have windows 7 home premium

Comment: Well then, please note that I said "on a Unix-like OS." Is Windows Unix-like? In Windows, you can try using the search bar (bottom of Start Menu), or use other Windows-specific search features. I highly recommend that you install Cygwin in which case the Unix advice would actually apply.

Comment: Also, instead of downloading Scala manually, you can get an MSI installer specifically created for Windows. It would add Scala to your Windows path, update the registry if needed, etc. For example, for Scala 2.11.2, you can get it here: http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.2/scala-2.11.2.msi

Comment: it is next step for the tutorial

Comment: Excuse me, what tutorial? Could you be more specific in general if you need something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61311/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-marekinfo).

Comment: @KickButtowski: Don't take things to chat unless they're off topic. This is on topic. Taking this to chat doesn't help anyone coming to this thread and trying to solve a similar problem. Also you're being downovoted because you didn't provide nearly enough information in your question, and you continually respond with things like "didn't work"